Is it true that if $ab$ is an idempotent element of a ring $R$ then $ba$ is also idempotent?
Let $R$ be a ring. Suppose $ab$ is an idempotent element for some $a,b\in R$. Let us try to prove $ba$ is also idempotent.
$(ba)^2=baba=b(abab)a=(ba)^3$.
But we can't say that $(ba)^2=ba$ from here. Is there any counterexample?

Take $a=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\ 
    0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ and
$b=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$. Then $ab=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$, but $ba=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\ 
    0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$.

Let $R$ be a ring and $a,b \in R$. Set $e=ab$ and $f=ba$ and suppose that $e$ is an idempotent.
Consider the principal ideals $Re$ and $Rf$. Since $ea=af$ and $be=fb$, writing $r_x\colon R\to R$ for the map $r_x(z)=zx$ we have a commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Re @>{r_e}>> Re \\
@V{r_a}VV @A{r_b}AA \\
Raf @>{\iota}>> Rf
\end{CD}
$$
where $\iota\colon Raf \to Rf$ denotes the inclusion map. Since $e^2=e$, $r_e$ is the identity map on $Re$ and so $r_b$ is a split surjection of left $R$-modules. Thus $Rf = r_a(Re)\oplus \ker(r_b)$. Moreover, $r_a(Re) = r_a(r_b(Rf))= Rf^2$ and since, for $xf \in Rf$ we have
$$
xf = (xf-r_ar_b(xf))+r_ar_b(xf) = (xf-xf^2)+xf^2 = xf(1-f) + xf^2
$$
it follows that $\ker(r_b) = Rf(1-f)$ and thus $Rf = Rf^2\oplus Rf(1-f)$, and $r_b\colon Rf^2 \to Re$ is an isomorphism of left $R$-modules with inverse $r_a$, and $r_a \circ r_b = r_f$ so that $r_f$ acts on $Rf$ as the projection to $Rf^2$. Thus we get the following commutative diagram, where bottom row is an exact sequence split by $r_a$.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@. @. Rf^2 @<{r_a}<< Re\\
@. @. @A{r_f}AA @| \\
0 @>>> Rf(1-f) @>{\iota}>> Rf=Rf^2\oplus Rf(1-f) @>{r_b}>> Re @>>> 0\\
\end{CD}
$$
Thus if $s= f^2$ and $n = f(1-f)$ then $f=s+n$ gives a "Jordan decomposition" of $f$ - $s$ and $n$ commute, indeed $sn=ns=0$, $f^2$ an idempotent (and hence semisimple) and $n=f(1-f)$  satisfying $n^2=0$.
It follows that the example $a = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, b = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ where $ab = 0$ is an idempotent but $ba=a$ is nilpotent, is in some sense the "only" way $ba$ can fail to be an idempotent. (Note that since $\text{tr}(ab)=\text{tr}(ba)$, if $a,b \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathsf k)$ are elements of a matrix algebra, then $ab$ and $(ba)^2$ must be idempotents of the same rank.)
